# Grails Asset Pipeline unchaged

Tags: caching, grails, compilation, asset-pipeline

I am new at Grails and I have something to ask who is expert in Grails. I use asset pipeline as resources management in my project. Everything is good, But there is an issue that, whether my resources file (scss filess, coffee script files, ...) is changed or not, the resources are compiled every time views are rendered (in dev and test environment). This makes  project run slow. Is there any solution to cache resource in asset pipeline, therefore if there is not any changing, the resources are not compiled. Thanks!

Comment: Any update on this issue?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using `require` to build a `require tree` and then refer the tree in your views then you can directly exclude raw resources getting pre-compiled every time by the plugin. For example:

If you have a require tree under `grails-app/assets/javascripts/application.js` as

```
//= require jquery
//= require app/models.js
//= require_tree views
//= require_self
```

or `.coffee`

```
#= require app/models.js
#= require test
#= require_self
#= require_tree .
```

And you don't want `models.js` getting pre-compiled everytime the view using the require tree is rendered then add the configuration as below:

```
grails.assets.excludes = ["app/models.js"] //app/*js for all resources under app
```

Above config informs the plugin to avoid the precompilation of resources and will only be compiled when the asset is referred in the view and asset has any changes.

You can find more on the [Usage documentation](http://bertramdev.github.io/asset-pipeline/guide/usage.html), mainly

> Optionally, assets can be excluded from processing if included by your
>   require tree. This can dramatically reduce compile time for your
>   assets.

Above config can be environment specific and can be used only for dev and test. For Production environment and/or war the pre-compilation would not matter.

```
environments {
    development {
        grails.assets.excludes = ["app/models.js"]
    }
}
```

Comment: Great answer. I love this plugin.

Comment: Close slight catch, excludes only matter in war creation and do not affect dev mode one bit. Dev maintains it's own internal cache and only on the fly recompiled if changes are detected

Comment: Which means resources cannot be excluded explicitly from the compilation when running app in dev mode? Which also means above setting should not work for OP? @davydotcom

Comment: I will have to check out and dig into the plugin as soon as I can. Nice work. @davydotcom